# XCode 5 - OpenURL not working in ViewController

Tags: xcode5

Getting error on `UIApplication Expecting ':'`.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction) pushButton{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.portfoliopathway.com"]];
}
```

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue you had?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket after `sharedApplication`.

```
-(IBAction) pushButton{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.portfoliopathway.com"]];
}
```